# how to create horizontally scrollable tableview and collectionview using swift 3

Tags: uitableview, swift3, uicollectionview, scrollable

Hello all I'm trying to implement scrollable collection view along with tableview.

Please find the attached images this is exactly what I'm trying to implement.

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3TZv.png).      [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IG47T.png).

but I can't figure out what layout would I use in order to achieve this goal, any input/tutorial would be appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: have a look at this https://github.com/alekseyn/EasyTableView
I don't think that scroll horizontally is a good idea and probably violates the Apple's HIG.

Comment: @santak hey thanks for the reply bt it would be great help of mine if you can give pinch of idea about how to implement this kind of UI.

Comment: https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Imageview list for category is basically a carousel control. So to achieve that you can check following two third party implementation. This will help you out.

https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

https://github.com/robertrr61/Image-Carousel

Otherwise you can also create your own control using Scrollview and image view with a little bit customization.